# Why are indicator applets not working?

Tags: indicator

The *indicator applet* and the *indicator applet session* are not showing anything for some reason. Last time I was on ubuntu they were working fine.

[image]

Does anyone know why this might happen?

The last time I was on Ubuntu, I had uninstalled unity, would that have anything to do with this?

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you're missing sound and message indicators. What happens when you install and run these?

Comment: thanks! looks like uninstalling unity deleted those indicators, so i reinstalled them. post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like you're missing sound and message indicators.

Uninstalling unity will have removed these indicators too, so you just need to reinstall them and hopefully restarting (logging off should do it) will put everything back.

`sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-messages indicator-sound`